# omnichannel - routing configurations

Tags: omnichannel

we will be using omnichannel to route cases & live agent requests to our users. We will have around 15 different language queues. Each of these queues is assigned to a case based on case assignment rules we have created.

My question is the following:
-It seems that we are not able to assign a routing configuration to more than 1 queue. What should we do in our case that we will be having 15 different queues? Should we create 15 different routing configurations and just assign 1-1 them with queues?

Answer (score 3):

No need to create 1:1 mapping between routing configuration and queue.
Routing configuration helps in deciding logic of allocation like Most Avaiable/Least Active and capacity consumption to be considered when one work item from queue is assigned to the agent.

Queue is something which holds work items till the point they are not assigned to someone.

In your case you can go ahead and create as many queues as you want and associate with only one routing configuration. All items will be treated based on the configuration done in routing configuration independent of what items you have added in queue like lead, case, etc.
Consider below snaps:

Queue List Veiw
[image: List View]

Queue 1
[image]
Queue 2
[image]
Queue 3
[image]
Routing configuraiton - Shwoing multiple queues
[image]

As per above you can attach multiple queues to the same routing configuration. In order to do that you need to edit queue and select routing configuration that you want to use.

So when to consider associating queues with different routing configurations:
 Queue helps you classifying work items lets say case could consume 5 unit of work but lead could consume 10 units of work then in such cases you need different routing configuration.

Hope this answers your questions.